# HTML path to the CSS file doesn't work without two dots

Tags: html, css, path

I want the path to the file to look like this: `"/assets/style/home.css"` 
But even though VSCode recognizes this path, and takes me there when I click it, the CSS doesn't appear on the page. It only appears when the path has the two dots: `"../assets/style/home.css"`

Any ideas on how can I fix this? This is what the entire path looks like:

[image: entire path of my files]

It's like that with every single path I use in this project, actually. I have to use the two dots for everything.

Comment: And why is that a problem?

Comment: The dev who's gonna finish the project said he needs this, I think because he plans on changing the file's location or something

Answer (score 1):

The "../" means that it is to return a directory, as your HTML file is inside the PAGES directory it is necessary to use the "../".

To call the css file like this "/assets/style/home.css" you need to move the assets folder into the PAGES folder

Answer (score 1):

The "../" before the file path is used to move up one directory level. It seems that the HTML file linking to the CSS file is in a subdirectory and the CSS file is in a directory one level up. If you want to use the path "/assets/style/home.css" the file should be in the same directory as the HTML file or a subdirectory of the HTML file.

You could also consider using absolute path instead of relative path, it would work regardless of where the HTML file is.
Upvote if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work if `RANDOMWEBSITE` is the root folder of the web server.

It will work in VSCode if you open the folder `RANDOMWEBSITE`, but perhaps your webserver is configured to use a different root folder above your directory.

For example the root folder might be `html`, and your website is at `html/RANDOMWEBSITE/`. In this case it would look for the css file in `html/assets/style/home.css`, rather than `html/RANDOMWEBSITE/assets/style/home.css`.

Check what the root folder of the webserver is set to and reconfigure, or alternativly remove the `RANDOMWEBSITE` folder from your folder tree and work within the existing root folder.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do that because .html is isn't "in the same line" as css. You can imagine that it's something like a crossroad if turn right but then you realise that you want to go left firstly you have to go back and than you can turn left. If you want do do "/assets/etc" you need to move you .html file to "randomwebsite/.html"